# How can be Sound energy get converted/conserved into the Universe's energy? How does it work?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, acoustics

Is energy constant in this universe? Or the energy is conserved?

Say an example, Whenever I take my foods, it converts into Mechanical Energy. And when I talk, it converts into Sound energy. So If, the energy in this universe is constant, then **How can this sound energy get conversed/converted?** Where does this energy goes? Doesn't it feels like it couldn't be restored again? Or, it could be?

The confusion araised when I think about this simple matter, It messes up every single logic I've learned.

I'm searching for this question of this matter for a long time and I can't.
 
After a lot of research, I thought this should be asked here for the perfectest answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens to energy lost as sound](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/289565/)

Answer (score 2):

The total energy of the universe should be constant since the whole universe by definition is a closed system, ie there is nothing else that the whole universe can dissipate its energy to.

Sounds energy can make other stuff move macroscopically. For instance, the sound of one drum can make a nearby drum vibrate, as long as the two drum have the same vibrational frequency (resonance)

Sounds energy can become heat and this is the main result of sound in most cases. In fact, all forms of energy will "eventually" become heat with overwhelming probability. This is due to the second law of thermodynamics (entropy of very large systems will increase with overwhelming probability). More ordered (low entropy) form of energy, like collective vibration of drum or air will eventually become less ordered heat that has higher entropy.

This is the reason why more ordered sound energy can spontaneously become less ordered heat... while heat can't spontaneously become sound. Heat can only become sound when they are embedded in a larger system like a car engine. In this case, the total entropy of {the engine, the fuel, the hot air inside the engine, the cold air outside} will still increase. However, local entropy for part of the system {hot air inside} can happen to decrease (from disordered hot air inside engine to more ordered slightly less hot air and sound inside the engine). However, when looking at the whole system, the total entropy will still increase, converting more ordered form of energy of the fuel into less ordered form of energy that is the heat at the end.